# Fabric.js strokeWidth causes objects to move (translate) on some SVG

Tags: svg

I have an issue with a select number of SVG patterns that I have. It doesn't happen with all of my SVG's, just a handful, which is frustrating.

Basically when I add a stroke color to an object, the object will show the stroke colour ok, but as soon as I increase the stroke width, it will translate the object either horizontally or vertically (depends on the SVG) and increase the size of the bounding box.

I have a text input field that takes a number, then I have a button to fire the stroke width change.

```
$("#btnstrokew").click(function()
{
    var width = $("#stroke-width").val();

    var activeGroup = canvas.getActiveObjects();
    if (activeGroup.length == 1) 
    {
        canvas.getActiveObject().set("strokeWidth", width);
    }
    else if(activeGroup.length > 1)
    {
        var actObj = canvas.getActiveObjects();
        actObj.forEach(function (object) {
            object.set("strokeWidth", width);
        });
    }
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
    save(true);
});
```

I just want the object to stay where it is and increase the strokewidth.

Can anyone please shed some light as to why it is doing it?

Answer (score 2):

ok I figured it out.

I needed to ParseInt or ParseFloat on the value.

```
canvas.getActiveObject().set("strokeWidth", parseFloat(width));
```